# How to fix "provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found" in modular java project with jakarta.json

Tags: java, json, gradle

I am using `jakarta.json` in a modular project built in Eclipse 2022-06 using Gradle. At runtime I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.json.JsonException: Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found
    at jakarta.json@2.0.1/jakarta.json.spi.JsonProvider.provider(JsonProvider.java:75)
    at jakarta.json@2.0.1/jakarta.json.Json.createObjectBuilder(Json.java:275)
    at mytest/Test2.Main.main(Main.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at jakarta.json@2.0.1/jakarta.json.spi.JsonProvider.provider(JsonProvider.java:72)
    ... 2 more
```

which to me looks clear: the implementation classes for json are missing. What I don' understand is why, because they are included in the `jakarta.json` module.

[image]

I setup a minimal project to reproduce the error.
Here below my `module-info.java`

```
module mytest {
  requires jakarta.json;
}
```

and `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.9'
}

apply plugin: 'eclipse'

eclipse.classpath.file {
    whenMerged {
        entries.findAll { isModule(it) }.each { it.entryAttributes['module'] = 'true' }
    }
}

boolean isModule(entry) {
    // filter java 9 modules
    entry.kind == 'lib'  // Only libraries can be modules
}
application {
    mainModule = "mytest" 
    mainClass = "Test2.Main"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/jakarta.json
    implementation 'org.glassfish:jakarta.json:2.0.1'
}
```

Can anybody help please?

Comment: One way to solve the problem is to separate the provider classes. As explained here [https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/pull/63](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/pull/63) an implementation is [Eclipse Parsson](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/parsson). So introducing this dependency `implementation 'org.eclipse.parsson:parsson:1.1.1'` and taking the api `implementation 'jakarta.json:jakarta.json-api:2.1.1'` is a working solution.

Comment: why don't you post this as an answer?
Your comment has helped me solve a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem is to separate the provider classes. As explained here https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/pull/63 an implementation is [Eclispe Parsson](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/parsson). So introducing this dependency `implementation 'org.eclipse.parsson:parsson:1.1.1'` and taking the api implementation `'jakarta.json:jakarta.json-api:2.1.1'` is a working solution.